# Django template can't see CSS files

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I'm building a django app and I can't get the templates to see the CSS files...  My settings.py file looks like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I've got the CSS files in /mysite/media/css/ and the template code contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site_base.css" />`
```

then, in the url.py file I have:

```
# DEVELOPMENT ONLY
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': '/media'}),
```

but the development server serves the plain html (without styles). What am I doing wrong?

--

OK - I got it working based on what you folks have said.  The answer is:

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'd://web//mysite//media//'  #absolute path to media
MEDIA_URL = '/mymedia/' #because admin already using /media
```

site_base.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mymedia/css/site_base.css" />
```

urls.py

```
from mysite import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^mymedia/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  
         {'document_root':     settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

And voila! It works.

Comment: Ok...upvote for helping me get unstuck but...there **is no** `/mymedia/` directory inside of `/media/`...so, how does it require it in the `href`? Where is it looking?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in the "development only" block in your urls.py you need to change

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': '/media'}),
```

to...

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Answer (score 5):

`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is set to `\media\` by default, and is probably 'stealing' the path. Change that setting, or use a different one for non-admin media - eg `site_media` or `assets`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I was pulling my hair out already! It's not the first time that I found your answers to django questions very helpful, so I guess it's just a big thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On the dev server, I like to cheat and put the following in my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^includes/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/path/to/static/files'}),
    )
```

That way anything in the project under the "/includes" folder is server by the dev server. You could just change that to "/media".

Answer (score 1):

It also worked for me, thanks guys !!

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/pi/ewspaces/ws-classic/xima/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/statics/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^statics/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  
     {'document_root':     settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

inside templates:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/statics/css/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: this also worked for me but I am wondering what do i need to change when I will deploy project on web.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to get jQuery to work. My fix was to add an alias to my Apache httpd.conf file that pointed to the folder containing the .js. You could do the same with your CSS folder.