# Django extends template

Tags: python, django, extends

i have simple django/python app and i got 1 page - create.html. So i want to extend this page to use index.html. Everything work (no errors) and when the page is loaded all data from create.html and all text from index.html present but no formating is available - images and css that must be loaded from index.html is not loaded. When i load index.html in browser looks ok. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

here is the code of templates:

**create.html**

```
    {% extends "index.html" %}

{% block title %}Projects{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if projects %}
        <table  border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Name</td>
                <td align="center">Description</td>
                <td align="center">Priority</td>
                <td align="center">X</td>
            </tr>
            {% for p in projects %}
            <tr>
                <td> <a href="/tasks/{{p.id}}/">{{p.Name}}</a> </td>
                <td>{{p.Description}} </td>
                <td> {{p.Priority.Name}} </td>
                <td> <a href="/editproject/{{p.id}}/">Edit</a> <a href="/deleteproject/{{p.id}}/">Delete</a> </td>
            <tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    {% else %}
        <p>No active projects.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**and index.html:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

<div class="PostContent">

<img class="article" src="images/spectacles.gif" alt="an image" style="float: left" />
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
<a href="#" title="link">link</a>, <a class="visited" href="#" title="visited link">visited link</a>, 
 <a class="hover" href="#" title="hovered link">hovered link</a> consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Quisque sed felis. Aliquam sit amet felis. Mauris semper, 
velit semper laoreet dictum, quam diam dictum urna, nec placerat elit nisl 
in quam. Etiam augue pede, molestie eget, rhoncus at, convallis ut, eros.</p>

    ....
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you include code of these templates?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are extending base.html and not index.html.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, look at the first line of your content.html:

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
```

Change this to

```
  {% extends "index.html" %}
```

(or rename index.html to be base.html)

Comment: sorry i try something and "base" is left but no mater that when is index.html the problem perist

Answer (score 1):

Ahaa find where is the problem!
MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL was not set up :-( after edit them everything work ok.

[Django template can't see CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075753/django-template-cant-see-css-files)